# Odd behavior with has_many :through and default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through, default-scope

We've got our basic has_many through: for Users and Companies.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extends CompanyMethods
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :companies, through: company_users

  has_many :orders
end

class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  validates_uniqueness_of :company_id, scope: :user_id
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :users, through: company_users
end
```

Then we have this `CompanyMethods` lib that adds a `default_scope` to User:

```
module CompanyMethods
  def self.extended(klass)
    klass.class_eval do
      default_scope do
        c_ids = Authorization.current_company_ids
        includes(:companies).where(companies: { id: c_ids })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So when we call `User.find_by_email('michael@widgetworks.com')` we get back only users that are scoped by `Authorization.current_company_ids`.

Here's the sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `users`.id FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `company_users` ON `company_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` ON `companies`.`id` = `company_users`.`company_id` WHERE `companies`.`id` IN (4) AND `users`.`email` = 'michael@widgetworks.com' LIMIT 1
```

All this is fine and dandy for a lot of instances. But here's where it starts to get funky.

When another object, for example a CreditCard calls an association that goes through User, the `companies.id` scope gets called on the child object.

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, through: :user_profile
  has_many :orders, through: :user
end

class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here's the sql that it generates:

```
SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders` INNER JOIN `users` ON `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `user_profiles` ON `users`.`id` = `user_profiles`.`user_id` WHERE `orders`.`company_id` IN (4) AND `companies`.`id` IN (4) AND `user_profiles`.`id` = 47717
```

`credit_card.orders` throws an error because of it's SQL query is calling  "`companies`.`id` IN (4)" on `reservation` when it should only be calling it on `user`.

I've been able to get around the problem with a hack of instead of using a `through` association, I just wrote a method named `reservations` on CreditCard.

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, through: :user_profile

  def orders
    user.orders
  end
end
```

That pretty much fixes the problem, but it's not a great solution.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but it looks like there are 2 different User {} models defined with the same name.  Is this just for the example?

Comment: @ValerieAsensio Sorry. That was just for example. Hopefully it's clearer now.